# C++ stringstream inline

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

I would like to use `std::stringstream` to create formatted strings, but use the class inline so I don't have `stringstream` local variables flying around. What I mean is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test = ((std::ostringstream&)
         (std::ostringstream("") << "This is a test: " << 50.1 << "abc")
         ).str();
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine in GCC, however the output is the following:

> "0x401d0a50.1abc"

So it seems that `stringstream` treats the first string as a pointer and outputs the address. Subsequent `operator<<`'s work fine.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75a72343fac11175)

Comment: This sounds like a missing include somewhere.  Are you sure you have included both `<sstream>` and `<ostream>`?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the code to show the complete file. This should compile and returns the output I've described above. Namely it seems to treat the first string as a pointer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen As per my corrected answer: what he is observing is actually the required behavior, according to the standard, and if you can't observe it, your compiler is broken (or seriously out of date---the critical rule was introduced into C++ around 1990).

Comment: @BaummitAugen [Reproduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a2ca1cc43cdf4fa) without `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I used gcc4.9, it is not that old.

Comment: So this rule changed with c++11?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I used g++ 4.8, and got the same behavior he did.  Adding `-std=c++11` seems to change it, so maybe they changed something in C++11 to make it work.

Comment: @ElOmmy Probably something related to rvalue references.  (I hope not: although it would be convenient in this case, in generally, the rule forbidding initializing references with a temporary was introduced because not doing so was found to be too error prone.)

Comment: Hmm so I just tested this in Microsoft VC++ 2013. It also produces the  correct output. This is a C++11 compiler as well. So I would suspect there's a change in the standard?

Comment: @ElOmmy Not so sure about Microsoft.  The last time I checked, they still allowed initializing a non-const reference with a temporary.  Non-conformant, but that's not the sort of thing which bothers Microsoft too much.

Comment: Could anyone try clang?

Comment: [Clang does the same thing as gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91226831b0078351).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that the `<<` operator is a member for `void const*`, but a free function taking an `std::ostream&` as the left hand argument for `char const*`.  Your `std::ostringstream( "" )` is a temporary: you can call member functions (even non-const member functions) on it, but a temporary cannot be used to initialize the non-const reference of the global function.

EDIT:

Two points: first, as has been pointed out, g++ does do what you
want if you specify `-std=c++11`.  As T.C. points out, this is
specified in §27.7.3.9, which provides a template overload for
all `<<` with an rvalue reference for the `std::istream`
parameter.
And second, the classic work around is
to start the expression `std::ostringstream( "" ).flush() <<...`.  `flush` is a member function (and so can be called on
a temporary) which returns an `std::ostream&` (so everything
else chains nicely); it also does nothing on
a `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply. I've updated the code above to show the full file with includes. So I include <iostream>, <sstream>, <ostream>, and <string>. Tried including <istream> as well, but this did not change anything unfortunately. The missing include makes sense, but which stl header would be missing?

Comment: @ElOmmy And I've updated my answer to give the correct reason:-).  Sorry that my initial comments were misleading.

Comment: Also, if this is of interest, this seems to be a way around this problem:  use *std::auto_ptr<std::ostringstream>(new std::ostringstream("")) instead of std::ostringstream("").  Not pretty, but doesn't matter since I'm wrapping this in a macro anyways.

Comment: @ElOmmy There are simpler solutions:-).  (And of course, you'd need `*std::auto_ptr<std::ostringstream>(...)` in order to get the reference rather than something pointer-like.)

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The C++11 standard special-cases rvalue streams with an extra template `operator<<` overload. §27.7.3.9 of the standard:

> **Rvalue stream insertion [ostream.rvalue]**
>
> ```
> template <class charT, class traits, class T>
> basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
> operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
> ```
>
> Effects: `os << x`
>
> Returns: `os`

It's obviously a better match than the member `operator<<` that takes a `const void *` and hence is selected by overload resolution in C++11 mode. In C++98 mode this overload doesn't exist (since there are no rvalue references) and the only viable overload is the member `operator<<` (since, as James Kanze explains in his answer, the temporary can't bind to the non-const lvalue reference in the free `operator<<` overload that takes a `const char *`).